# Your PHP MySQL library version differs from your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql, linux, debian

I've recently upgraded MySQL on my Debian 5.0.4 server to 5.1. Now phpMyAdmin shows the following warning:

`Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.43`

Is it likely to cause any problems?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The message indicates that :

- You are using **version 5.1.43 of MySQL server**
- But that the **library that's used by PHP** to communicate with that server has been compiled to communicate with a **version 5.0.x** of MySQL.

In theory, **this should not cause any real problem** : minor versions tend to be compatible ; but you might need to update the library that's used by PHP ; maybe some package like "`libmysql`", or something like that *(I don't have a Debian machine)*

If you want to make that warning disappear *(even if I'm not sure it could really cause any big problem)*, you'll have to **update the PHP component** that is used to communicate with MySQL.

Note : With the dependancies, it might not be that easy, actually, to upgrade just one package...

I would say that you'd have to update something like `php5-mysql` ; which means :

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

*(According to [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-debian-package-management-cheat-sheet.html) -- amongst others -- to update a single package, your must use `install`)*

If you are using `aptitude`, and not apt-get... Not sure about the right option that you should use to update only one package ; still, `aptitude safe-upgrade` should present you with a list of packages it will upgrade, which will allow you to decide whether or not you wish to continue...

But you said in a comment to another answer that Debian ships by default with MySQL 5.0 -- which means the "official" module for PHP is probably compiled against libmysql 5.0, and not libmysql 5.1.

To solve that problem, you'll have to either :

- Find a repository that provides PHP *(or, at least, the `mysql` extension)* compiled against libmysql 5.1
- Or **re-compile** PHP and/or the `mysql` extension against the version of libmysql that's currently used on your system -- i.e. libmysql 5.1

Comment: Since the above answer is the best, I'll add here. The problem package is libmysqlclient15off which is a holdover from upgrading from an older release. Few of the older packages weren't upgraded or were dropped leaving it around on some hosts. I my case an old mydns install still depended on the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get update mysql-client`.

Comment: I don't think this would work. My mysql-client (running from the console) is up-to-date, I was asking about the MySQL module for PHP. The problem stems from the fact that Debian 5 ships with MySQL 5.0 by default, and this is the version of the MySQL library included with PHP 5.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this in the phpMyAdmin console - I run Debian 8 on Google cloud and recently upgraded to mysql 5.7.21. I had to run the PHP NativeDriver to get this to subside

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically have php-mysql and php-mysql**nd** drivers...

On CentOS 7, I made version error go away by:

```
yum remove php-mysql.x86_64     
yum install php-mysqlnd.x86_64
```

Note that removing `php-mysql` also removed **phpMyAdmin**, but I installed it again without any problems.

Error related to lib versions is gone now, but not sure if phpMyAdmin just doesn't check versions of drivers for the mysqlnd version or the php-mysqlnd is just more compatible.

Answer (score -1):

In Debian/Ubuntu you can overcome that notification by using the following command in the latest repository defined in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade mysql-client
```

That will solve your problem perfectly.

Have a great day.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get update php5-mysql
```

Comment: According to `man`: "update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources", not to update a single package.

Comment: if you specify install, apt-get will update the package and the depencies that don't meet the version requirements