# Mysql version is different in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just upgraded my MYSQL version from 
5.5.40 to 5.6.22 
but my PHPMYADMIN still show the same old version on Home Page

In terminal I checked version
mysql --version   ==>   5.6.22

But when I check with "select version()" command inside Terminal and PHPMYADMIN
I got correct version 5.6.22

But on home page of PHPMYADMIN I get 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

In a post I read that there might be two mysql clients installed and may be phpmyadmin is referring to old client. If this is the case how can I delete old-client

Comment: maybe it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357909/your-php-mysql-library-version-differs-from-your-mysql-server-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing php-mysql and installing php-mysqlnd. Will automatically done by following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install phpmyadmin
```

Or you can try reinstalling your phpmyadmin