# Phpmyadmin shows blank page

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently we have upgraded our mysql from 5.5.x to 5.6.x in an Ubuntu 12.04, also we have changed php5-mysql library with php5-mysqlnd(Which is recommended from MySql).

Since our change in library phpmyadmin stopped working and shows a blank page.

I have followed so many forum and advises from forum contributor but have not had success so far.

I also used ubuntu repository as suggested in this other topic at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702456/mysql-version-is-different-in-phpmyadmin) ppa:nijel which I believe has the modified phpmyadmin package and include the support of php5-mysqlnd, but still no success.

I also have enabled highest verbosity on the php.ini but still nor error or warning is generating in any log, using chrome developer tools it shows "500 Internal Server Error".

I am clueless now, if anyone can help me to determine what I may be missing obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after multiple uninstall, purge and reinstall of phpmyadmin I did not get a success.

Finally I used bruit-force approach and from another Linux server where phpmyadmin was running properly I copied all i.e. /usr/share/phpmyadmin, /etc/phpmyadmin and /var/lib/phpmyadmin folders and over write them in the problematic server.

Every thing works perfectly now.

Thanks for help Vibhas... I just thuoght to post just for someone's help.

Answer (score 2):

Check Mysql & Php error log files located at /var/log/mysql/error.log and /var/log/apache2/error.log respectively

Comment: Thanks Vibhas for helping me, but even after enabling display_error to On and error_reporting = E_ALL and log path to /var/log/apache2/error.log there is no log generating either on Apache error log or mysql error log. If you wish I can share the log files and configuration files for review.

Comment: Are you able to run php files from browser,check if apache is running properly normally we get 500 error when files don't have appropiate permissions to run.

Comment: I have changed /etc/phpmyadmin, /usr/share/phpmyadmin and /var/lib/phpmyadmin all recursively with ownership as www-data:www-data, but still blank page :(

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a very similar error and I thought I would leave my solution here in case anyone finds this searching for my error. The difference was, that phpMyAdmin showed a blank page after a successful login.

The solution was, removing the "X-Frame-Options: Deny" header.

When setting up the webserver, I didn't remember that phpMyAdmin would rely on iFrames to serve its interface.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone (like I was) is using phpmyadmin via xampp on windows and has skype turned on - try turning skype off (or configure xampp to use another port).

Answer (score 1):

A web search for [phpmyadmin blank page] shows many people are having this problem and there are almost as many different solutions proposed. So let me add one more after spending a day and finally having success:

When the blank page was displaying, I opened Developer Tools (Command-Option-i on Mac in Chrome or Brave). I immediately observed multiple instances of failing to load .js files from phpmyadmin/js/dist. Checking that directory I found that it was indeed empty.

I then went to https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and downloaded the zip file into a different location. When I unzipped it, I found js/dist did in fact contain many .js files. I copied all of these files to my webserver's phpmyadmin/js/dist directory. And the problem was solved! I now have a working page.

I hope that helps some of you.

Perhaps I should add that I installed phpmyadmin using the Composer install method (% composer create-project phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin). I did it a second time in an offline directory and again the js/dist directory was empty. I don't know if that means I did something wrong or if that install method is broken.

Comment: This is what worked for me. This answer should be more appreciated. I also thought this would solve the problem but didn't know where to find the "phpmyadmin" files. Thank you so much. Wish I found it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with phpmyadmin (phpmyadmin was returning a blank page). It was alright once I reinstalled phpmyadmin using:

```
apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin
```

If you are not root:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

When i changed this inside the config.inc.php:

`$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/tmp';
 $cfg['SaveDir'] = '/tmp';`

to:

`$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';`

and reloaded the page then it worked directly!

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but it happened to me when I realised after a cPanel password reset I did not check the "Synchronize MySQL password" option. 
This used to be defaulted as checked in previous cPanel versions.

To fix all I did was reset my cPanel password again and selected the "Synchronize MySQL password" checkbox and PhpMyAdmin was back.

Hope this helps others, and if its causing a big issue cPanel should select this option by default again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience after installing mysql 5.5.60 and phpmyadmin 4.2.12 and what did the trick for me was changing folder ownership for /var/lib/php/session which was the solution in [another case](https://serverfault.com/questions/70634/what-permissions-ownership-to-set-on-php-sessions-folder-when-running-fastcgi#340417) for getting php-scripts tu run in general. In my case user `www-data` is trying to execute related scripts, so I set folder permissions accordingly

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php5/
```

and the page appeared as expected.